# Jquery mobile blue border arround body

Tags: jquery, mobile

When I insert jquery mobile on my page, blue border appearing all around the body (not on form elements) on chrome and safari...how can I remove it?

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and not linked jquery mobile css...only jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow...whats wrong about my question? I have to know it for the future questions..

Comment: Btw, I do not downvote your question; did you check the link?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my answer

.ui-page {outline: none;}

fix it...